# ¿Como hago para sacar las keys de un JSON en python y luego ponerlas en un array?

Tags: python, array, json

Eso pues, tengo un JSON:

```
{ 
  "latitude": 0, 
  "longitude": 0, 
  "sensors": {}, 
  "station_id": 0, 
  "object_id": 0,
  "timestamp": 0
}
```

y quiero sacar las keys, que aca serian: `"latitude"`, `"longitude"`, `"sensors"`, `"station_id"`, `"object_id"` y `"timestamp"`, para luego sacarlas y colocarlas en un array asi:

```
palabras: ["latitude", "longitude", "sensors", "station_id", "object_id", "timestamp"]
```

Mi idea era poner algo asi:

```
print(JSON) #este es el JSON
palabras = []
for (key in JSON):
    #aca se sacaria la key del JSON
    #aca se añadiria un append o algo asi para agregarle al array la key seleccionada
print(palabras)#aca se mostraria el array asi: ["latitude", "longitude", "sensors", "station_id", "object_id", "timestamp"]
```

Eso estaba pensando hacer, pero no se como sacar cada key del JSON y luego colocarlo en el array

Answer (score 0):

El método `keys()` sirve para obtener las claves de un diccionario, esto ya devuelve una lista pero de tipo `dict_values`, solo tendremos que convertirlo a lista con `list()`

```py
lista = list(JSON.keys())
```

Por cierto en Python no existen los array, en su lugar están las listas :)

Comment: sirvio bastante, gracias, ahora puedo revisarlo con otra lista que tengo